# Use Magic Methods in custom module

Tags: magento-1, magic-getter

I want to make use of Magic Methods in my Custom Module.

I created a new Model with different member variables (variable1, variable2) and I want to get them like getVariable1.

How do I need to declare those member variables? Can I set them on private? What else am I missing?

Somewhere I read I need to save them in `$_data['variable1']`, but that doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magic methods are implemented via `Varien_Object` class.

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $data;

        case 'set' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'uns' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->unsetData($key);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'has' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
}
```

You'll need to either extend that class or any other class which extends from `Varien_Object` like `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` for example. You are not required to define any variables or methods in your model as long as your method starts with `get`, `set`, `uns` and `has`, that is assuming you want them to work as magic methods.

So you can write something like this:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('namespace_module/sample');
$model->setSomeData('Hello');
echo $model->getSomeData();
```

If you do `Zend_Debug::dump($model);` you'll notice that your data is stored in `_data` property which is declared in `Varien_Object` class.

Example:

```
object(Namespace_Module_Model_Sample)#128 (7) {
  ["_data":protected] => array(1) {
    ["some_data"] => string(5) "Hello"
  }
  ["_hasDataChanges":protected] => bool(true)
  ["_origData":protected] => NULL
  ["_idFieldName":protected] => NULL
  ["_isDeleted":protected] => bool(false)
  ["_oldFieldsMap":protected] => array(0) {
  }
  ["_syncFieldsMap":protected] => array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!