# Magento 2 - Quesiton about the commented method in the beginning of the php file

Tags: magento2

I was looking for the implementation of `setCarrier()` and `getCarrier()`, what I found was in the beginning of `Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php` ([link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php#L19)), but they are commented with no function body like below...

```
 * @method string getCarrier()
 * @method \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate setCarrier(string $value)
```

And then I found a function using `getCarrier()` under the same php file, which is

```
public function importShippingRate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\AbstractResult $rate)
    {
        if ($rate instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error) {
            $this->setCode(
                $rate->getCarrier() . '_error'
            )->setCarrier(
                $rate->getCarrier()
            )->setCarrierTitle(
                $rate->getCarrierTitle()
            )->setErrorMessage(
                $rate->getErrorMessage()
            );
        } elseif ($rate instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method) {
            $this->setCode(
                $rate->getCarrier() . '_' . $rate->getMethod()
            )->setCarrier(
                $rate->getCarrier()
            )->setCarrierTitle(
                $rate->getCarrierTitle()
            )->setMethod(
                $rate->getMethod()
            )->setMethodTitle(
                $rate->getMethodTitle()
            )->setMethodDescription(
                $rate->getMethodDescription()
            )->setPrice(
                $rate->getPrice()
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

So I went to the `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\AbstractResult`, but the php file inside is [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/RateResult/AbstractResult.php), an empty class.

I have checked the `di.xml`, but nothing related was found. Are those functions internally interpreted into some other functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a way to document that a function exists, but it's being generated using `__call()`, probably in a parent class (in this case I believe it would be `Magento\Framework\DataObject`).

Comment: I found that magento 2 has the same mechanism like magent o 1.X, please refers to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52464/use-magic-methods-in-custom-module